# How can I send Image notification to IOS in FCM push notifications using Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, firebase-cloud-messaging

As in Android we can set image in Message Builder with AndroidConfig.builder()-> AndroidNotification.builder()-> .setImage(imageUrl)
How to set Image notification for IOS ApnsConfig.builder()-> fcmOptions are generating errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set mutable content true and then just add custom data with key as "image"

here is find below example helpful

```
ApnsConfig.builder().putCustomData("image",imageUrl).
                setAps(Aps.builder().setCategory(clickAction).setThreadId(clickAction).setMutableContent(true).build()).build();
```